# Open a HTML file with data using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm trying to use google script to display a bunch of data in a HTML file, however, my data doesn't seem to make it to the HTML file and I have no idea why. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here?

Path: `htmlList.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top" />
  </head>
  <body>
    My HTML page

    <? for(var i = 0; i <= (users.length -1); i++) { ?>

    <p><?= users[i].firstName ?></p>
    <? } ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Path: `Code.js`

```
function doGet(users) {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("htmlList");
  html.users = users;
  return html.evaluate().setTitle("Test my app");
}

function generateLinks() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var rr = spreadSheet.getLastRow();

  var users = [];
  for (var i = 3; i <= rr; i++) {
    var firstName = spreadSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();

    var user = {
      firstName: firstName
    };

    users.push(user);
  }

  doGet(users);
}
```

Comment: In your script, when `generateLinks()` is run, the value returned from `generateLinks()` doesn't work. And when `doGet(users)` is executed as Web Apps, `users` is not declared. So for example, how about modifying from `return html.evaluate().setTitle("Test my app")` to `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate().setTitle("Test my app"), "sample")`? By this, when `generateLinks()` is run, you can see the HTML at a dialog. But I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want. So can I ask you about your goal?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following what you're saying. When `generateLinks()` runs `doGet(users)` passes the users data to the function. If I use `Logger.log(users)` within `function doGet(users)` it displays all the data correctly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about `Open a HTML file with data using Google Script`? I cannot understand that how you want to use the function of `doGet()`. Do you want to open the HTML by Web Apps or dialog and side bar?

Comment: All I want to do is pass the users data to a HTML file and have it open in a browser and display that data. Currently, the webpage opens if I publish it and it displays `My HTML page` however none of the users first names are displayed.

Comment: In your situation, you open the HTML using own browser by accessing to the URL of Web Apps. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sorry, I appreciate your help here. I'm a noob to google scripts. I'm running google scripts using the online editor. When I'm in the editor and I press the play button I want it to open a new tab in chrome and display the user data as webpage. This is only for me, it is not publicly avalible.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to open new tab for own browser using the created HTML data, when you run the function at the script editor.
- You are using the container-bound script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

In this modification, I used the following flow. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

1. By running `runScript()`, a dialog is opened.
2. The opened dialog runs a Javascript for opening new tab of the browser and open the URL of Web Apps.

   - At this time, `generateLinks()` is run from `doGet()`, and the values are retrieved and put to HTML data.
3. Close the dialog.

By this flow, when you run the function at the script editor, the created HTML is opened as new tab of your browser.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the container-bound script of Spreadsheet. And then, please redeploy Web Apps as new version. At that time, as a test case, please set `Execute the app as:` and `Who has access to the app:` as `Me` and `Anyone, even anonymous`, respectively. In this case, you are not required to modify the script of HTML side.

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("htmlList");
  html.users = generateLinks(); // Modified
  return html.evaluate().setTitle("Test my app");
}

function generateLinks() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var rr = spreadSheet.getLastRow();

  var users = [];
  for (var i = 3; i <= rr; i++) {
    var firstName = spreadSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();

    var user = {
      firstName: firstName
    };

    users.push(user);
  }
  return users; // Modified
}

// I added the following function. Please run this function.
function runScript() {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  var script = "<script>window.open('" + url + "', '_blank').focus();google.script.host.close();</script>";
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(script);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'sample');
}
```

- When `var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();` is used, the 1st sheet of Spreadsheet is used. So when you want to retrieve the values from the specific sheet, for example, please modify to `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheetName")`.

#### Note:

- **If you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)
- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: @bp123 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data on the spreadsheet looks something like this -

[image: Test Data]

And the desired output looks something like this (you're free to modify the CSS in your `.html` file) -

[image: Dummy output]

You can achieve this by using the following code -

For **Code.gs**:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getUsers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var users = ss.getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  return users;
}
```

For **Index.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">

    <script>
        function onSuccess1(users) {
            var div = document.getElementById('userFirstNames');
            div.innerHTML = users;
        }
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess1).getUsers();
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id='userFirstNames'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps.